# Need assistance with accessing mysql database using node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am trying to run a simple node sample for access a mysql db and am getting the following error-Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'ubuntu.local' (using password: YES)

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : '192.168.0.12',
  user     : 'root',
  password : 'password',
  database : 'app'
});

connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT * from users', function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log('The solution is: ', rows[0]);
});

connection.end();
```

The above is the code for accessing the mysql using node.js.Any suggestions as to what I may be doing wrong, thanks in advance.

Comment: can you connect to mysql from console ? `mysql -h 192.168.0.12 -u root -p app` (enter password after request)

Comment: most probably you need set host to 'localhost'

Comment: nope I cannot, execute the command you gave me, but if I replace the ip addr with localhost it works from the command line but in the node script I get the following error-connect ECONNREFUSED.

Comment: mysql host on the same server where node run ?

Comment: check the MySQL logs to ensure you're attempting to authenticate with the identity that you have entered (in particular that the hostnames match)

Comment: login to mysql console and run
`GRANT ALL ON app.* to 'root'@'ubuntu.local' identified with 'password';`  and retry your first approach

Comment: Thanks so much that worked!!!! Can you post that as an ans to this question?

Comment: Thanks @eicto! This also helped for ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR using nodejs and MariaDB.

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar problem where I was getting the same error.

The answer for me ended up being that I was using a different port. By default, mysql expects a port of 3306, but I was using MAMP, where the MySQL server port was specified as 8889. As soon as I added a port definition to my database connection, it was fine:

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    port: 8889,
    user: 'root',
    password : 'password',
    database : 'my_database'
});
```

NOTE: This is for Mac using MAMP, haven't tried it on ubuntu or Windows.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the exact same issue.  I was not able to connect via the mysql module in nodejs, but was able to connect via the mysql client in the terminal (mysql -u root -p1111 -h localhost mydb)

It turns out, the mysql module converts "localhost" to 127.0.0.1.
This would not work via the (mysql -u root -p1111 -h 127.0.0.1 mydb).
See [Issue 734](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/issues/734)

So I had to set a password for 127.0.0.1 in MySQL and it solved the problem.

Instructions

Connect to mysql via the console:

```
mysql -u root -p mysql
```

And Run

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'127.0.0.1' = PASSWORD('Add-Your_password-here');
```

[Source](http://nixcraft.com/showthread.php/14889-Mysql-root-localhost-can-log-but-not-as-127-0-0-1?s=603a93c1e72a954bebab15fe50b59cdd&p=26225&viewfull=1#post26225)

Comment: when run `mysql -u root -p mysql` get this error `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Answer (score 1):

I've been on this problem for a long time now and among all forums I did, one simple solution resolve my issue. My password was with some special character. I change it to a simpler one like "onlyletters" and it works perfectly. Probably a encoding problem in the nodejs mysql module, I can... Hope it would help some of you guys...

Comment: With me it was the password: [A-Za-z0-9\.]{64} worked for me,

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem,my nodejs project.I was using knex.js for querybuilder and it's configuration.

This problem occurs when host value is **127.0.0.1**,when i changed to 127.0.0.1 to localhost,the problem is gone away.

```
var knex = require('knex')({
    client: 'mysql',
    connection: {
        **host: 'localhost',**
        user: 'userNew',
        password: 'password',
        database: 'appDb'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The user might not have any administrative role assigned so he is not able to access the database. The user will need at least the SELECT privilege to connect.

More info here: 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-mysql-connections-navigator-management-users-and-privileges.html

Answer (score -1):

Actually the solution is easier than you think. Change the host to 127.0.0.1 for the database connection.

Comment: Would you please be able to provide a little more detail about why changing the host to "127.0.01" fixes the database connection? Because the OP is using an IP address that appears to be related to a database server.