# Sequelizejs-auto: cannot connect to server with user credentials

Tags: sequelize.js

according to the docs [here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto) i have set the command this way

```
sequelize-auto -h 127.0.0.1 -d fettle -u root -x 1234 -e mysql -o "./modelss"
```

i am currently using wamp for other projects, so i use `mysql` from that pack, all applications and programs that require connections from that `mysql` are working fine.. but this one throws me this error

```
[SequelizeAccessDeniedError: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)]
  name: 'SequelizeAccessDeniedError',
  message: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user \'root\'@\'localhost\' (using password: YES)',
  parent:
   { [Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)]
     code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
     errno: 1045,
     sqlState: '28000',
     fatal: true },
  original:
   { [Error: ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)]
     code: 'ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR',
     errno: 1045,
     sqlState: '28000',
     fatal: true } }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found out this was a bug, so this bug was fixed now.. the issue thread can be found in [here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-auto/issues/36)

Answer (score 0):

Comparing your command with the error logs, it looks like something in the stack is transforming `127.0.0.1` to `localhost`.

If you have confirmed that you can connect to MySQL with `mysql -u root -p 1234` (or with whatever the password's actual value is) then try the following:

- From the console: `mysql -u root -p 1234`
- In mysql: `SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('1234');`

**Source of suggested commands**

[Need assistance with accessing mysql database using node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437066/need-assistance-with-accessing-mysql-database-using-node-js)

**Other links**

- [github.com node-mysql issue #734](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/issues/734) - also suggests socket path as an alternative
- [github.com node-mysql issue #591](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql/issues/591) - different hostname pair but looks like same issue

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but I added double quotations to password and it worked.

```
-x "123"
```