# Javascript MySQL Error?

Tags: javascript, mysql

I set up all of my database information in javascript and It doesn't want to seem to connect. If it is connecting it doesn't update any data.

Here is my Query and Connection Code:
Full Code: https://pastebin.com/PBMW6UM8

Query Code:

```
  var sql = "UPDATE tf2 SET credits = ? WHERE steamid = " + mysql.escape(id)
  con.query(sql, [totalcash], function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
```

Or look for //Query Code in Pastebin.

Extra Variables

```
<script>totalcash='<?php echo $credits; ?>'</script>
<script>id='<?php $steamprofile['steamid']; ?>'</script>
```

Comment: By default, mysql expects a port of 3306. Your code doesnt specify a port. Are you sure your db is on 3306?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need assistance with accessing mysql database using node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13437066/need-assistance-with-accessing-mysql-database-using-node-js)

Comment: My Mysql port is 3306 and i also defined the port as 3306 but this didn't fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Connect to MySQL via the console and set a password for root user by running `SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'127.0.0.1' = PASSWORD('yourDesieredPassword');`

Then retry connecting Node using the code you already have, just with the updated password.

```
var con = mysql.createConnection({

  host: "localhost",

  user: "root",

  password: "yourDesiredPassword",

  database: "tf2"

});
```